Is it possible to use a heightmap to create displacement and use the object as a modular asset with the edges alligned with each other?
I'm trying to make my wall a little more interesting by using a heightmap on a subdivided face, which I then want to decimate to make it a little more manageable. But this method doesn't create seamless models, which is important in my case as I want to duplicate the object and use it side by side. The edges are fuzzy and the verts are not aligned at all.
My heightmap is seamless and the UV of the face covers the entire space.


You could scale the UVs a bit so that the model has the transitions from tile to tile and then cut the model with bisect operator at the seams to have them smoother. Manual work would be needed to fix the seams to match exactly though.
You could align the seams with geometry that is repeating to see if it could  make it easier, but I have not tested this. I suspect the problems are caused by geometry edges, so it could work better if you don't have the edges at the seams of the displacement map, but have extended geometry there instead. This could also be caused by image compression though.
